# Java '.class' expected error

Tags: java, variables, loops, scope, global-variables

My code below will get a compile error:  '.class' expected:

```
Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
char pop=stack.pop();
```

But if I change to this, compile succeeded:

```
char pop;
Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
pop=stack.pop();
```

What's the reason?

Full code is here:

```
 public class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {

        //char pop;
        if(s==null||s.length()==0)return true;
        Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
        stack.push(s.charAt(0));
        for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
            char c=s.charAt(i);
            if(c=='('||c=='['||c=='{')
                stack.push(c);
            else{
                if(!stack.isEmpty())
                    char pop=stack.pop();
                else
                    return false;
                if(c==')'&&pop!='(') return false;
                else if(c==']'&&pop!='[') return false;
                else if(c=='}'&&pop!='{') return false;
            }
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your full code? Is there anything before / after it that might trigger a `.class` expected?

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: This in itself doesn't cause the error you describe.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you post full but short code that would allow us reproduce it?

Comment: Its working.. with no compilation error.

Comment: uncomment `char pop` and in your `if` use `pop=stack.pop();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used pop as a local variable inside a if condition. It should be global, as you are using pop value later. 
Although in else condition there will be no use of pop. But it will still show compilation error.
In your code snippet:

```
else{
            if(!stack.isEmpty())
                char pop=stack.pop(); // Here you initialized the value inside a condition.
            else
                return false;
            if(c==')'&&pop!='(') return false;
            else if(c==']'&&pop!='[') return false;// Using the value.
            else if(c=='}'&&pop!='{') return false;// Using the value.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code would compile

```
if (!stack.isEmpty())
    char pop = stack.pop();
else
```

is would be the same as (notice `{...}` brackets that represents variables scope)

```
if (!stack.isEmpty()){
    char pop = stack.pop();
} else
```

so it would mean that you are just getting result of `stack.pop()` and storing it in variable `char pop` which wouldn't be accessible anywhere outside of this block.
Since this instruction is the only one that would be executed in case of success of `if` condition it means that storing result of `pop()` is redundant and sign of problem with design.

To solve this problem declare `char pop` somewhere before your `if` statement so it can be accessed after `if` blocks.

```
char pop; //make sure that this variable will be initialized before you use it
if (!stack.isEmpty())
    pop = stack.pop();
else
```

Answer (score 0):

issue might exists in below code :

```
if(!stack.isEmpty())         // here you will need to provide curly braces to define pop's scope
     char pop=stack.pop();
```

Also, if you declare `pop` outside, I see it in your commented code `//char pop`, you will have to remove char declaration of pop in above if condition which would make more sense as you are trying to use it outside your if condition.